# Find rows for interval in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, database-design, indexing

SO,

**The problem**

I have a very simple - at first glance - problem. Assuming that I have data set with two meaningful columns: `from` and `till`. This data set isn't yet in DB. I need to search through this data set and for some `X` find rows where condition `from < X < till` is true. For example, I have rows (`id` added just for identifying rows, it doesn't mean that rows are in DB):

```
id from till
------------
1  100  200
2  120  200
3  1000 1050
4  1100 1500
```

and I want to find rows for `X = 125`. That will be rows # `1` and `2`. I.e. intervals may intersect, but they are always correct (`from` is always lesser than `till`). Also, strict condition is that all three: `from`, `till` and `X` are unsigned integers. Besides, with high probability, intervals will not be nested too heavily - so, if intersection would be, it will not be a case, when, for example, some interval is nested to all others (practically that means that certain interval is a reliable condition which will not mean full table)

Moving to the deal. My data set could be huge (around ~500.000.000 rows) - and I need to store it somehow in DB. There is no restrictions for DB structure - it can be anything, I'm free to chose proper solution (that it why my data set is not in DB yet). So, problem is - how to store that in DB to make querying rows for given `X` as fast as possible?

**My approach**

At first glance - it's very simple. We just create columns for `from` and `till`, filling them with our data set and here we are. Really? Not. Why? Because such table structure will not allow to build any good index for using it in query. If we'll create index on two columns `(from, till)` it will have no sense in terms of our problem - and if we'll create two separate indexes on two columns `from` and `till` - they will both have low selectivity. Why? Imagine that we have row with `from = 100.000.000` and `till = 100.000.200`. Then querying `WHERE 100.000.000 < X AND X < 100.000.200` will not use index - because that condition with split indexes will produce near full scan for each index. And there's where tricky part is - obviously, that condition specifies *very narrow* part of table (i.e. logically, it is good) - but if we're speaking about separate conditions - it's crap, because each of them is near full scan.

My next though was to create some function which will take two arguments and create then [bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) transition to some line set of numbers. Since my `from` and `till` are integers - and, what's important - positive integers, and also `from` < `till` always, sample of such function will be `from^2 + till^2`. So, ok, we'll translate our intervals to some numbers. But, unfortunately, to operate on this numbers and `X` we'll have to rely on original `from` and `till` - i.e. it seems that's not a case for such idea. But may be I'm missing something?

**The question**

Currently, I have no completed clear idea - how to implement this. So - again, I'm free to chose any architecture, but it should fit requirement of fast querying for needed rows by `X`.  And the question is - what table structure (columns, indexes e t.c.) could be proposed here? We are also free to store additional tables (however, it will be good if their sizes will not be too high). Of course, since we're free to define table structure, we can change querying for `X` too (i.e. if some structure will need to add some condition to that query - it is ok, the only need is to achieve final goal).

Comment: May be something is unclear? Or there is no solution? (if there are proofs for that - I would be welcome to see them as an answer)

Comment: wow very very nice question +1 what storage engine are you planning to use?

Comment: @RaymondNijland - any one. I don' care what tools will be needed. Consider I'm an architect and root user on target host. Any solution is good if it answers my question

Comment: If you are not bound to a DB, you can use an interval tree to implement this. It has logarithmic insert/delete/lookup times.

Comment: @NikiC well, actually, I'm bound to DB. But I'm free to use any DB structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reduce the impact of the query over all rows running the comparison function to find out if that row matches the span of numbers X lies in or not.

As you have outlined, the effectiveness of some common index is not of much use because of the sheer amount of numbers / row ratio.

This is where I would start. Why not reduce the resolution and use that as an index?

Also how large do the spans get? You have so far 100, 80, 50, 400.

Assuming that the size of a span is not up to the superset of all values but instead normally a little fraction of it (e.g. max 1 000 by a superset of  500 000 000 values), why not index `from` but at lower resultion, e.g. divided by 1 000.

That will greatly reduce the index-space to 500 000 entries on such a low resolution helper-column. You then can use std. math in the `WHERE` part of the query to use that index, too to find a superset of possible matching rows. The more expensive comparisons (the exact `BETWEEN`) can then be deffered on only these possible matching rows.

This perhaps is not such an academic solution to the problem but might give you the performance you're looking for.

**Edit:** As @NikiC kindly pointed out and for the academic solution, there is a paper by Hans-Peter Kriegel, Marco Pötke and Thomas Seidl:

- [The Relational Interval Tree: Manage Interval Data Efficiently
  in Your Relational Database (PDF)](http://www.dbs.informatik.uni-muenchen.de/Forschung/CAD/presentations/RI-Tree.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I've ended for now with option like this. However, I'd like what you've called "academic" solution - but this way is better than nothing

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to [partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html) your table. Specifically using [range partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-range.html). This coupled with indexes on your `from` and `till` columns should give you an acceptable level of performance.

Here is a basic example:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `from` bigint unsigned not null,
    `till` bigint unsigned not null,
PRIMARY KEY (`from`,`till`),
INDEX myTableIdx1 (`from`),
INDEX myTableIdx2 (`till`)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (`from`) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (200000),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (400000),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (600000),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (800000),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (1000000),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (1200000),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (1400000),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (1600000),
    PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (1800000),
    PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (2000000),
-- etc etc
    PARTITION pEnd VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

This approach does make the assumption that your version of MySQL supports partitioning and that you can divide your table into meaningful partitions based on the data!

PS You may want to choose a different column name other than `from`....

Comment: So you're suggesting just to split big problem into small problems - i.e. I still won't be able to search effectively inside partition (because no indexes could be used). And also - my intervals could intersect, so I don't think partitioning is a great idea (because of intersections, query may touch too many partitions). I can use them - but I don't think this will help a case, unfortunately

Comment: I am suggesting splitting it into a smaller problem - isn't that what an effective index search does anyway? Furthermore, given your example data and queries, how can one query touch more than one partition? Anyway, up to you really, you'll know better whether partitioning is appropriate or not

Comment: No - because if I'll have two rows, one with `from=100, till=100.000.001` and second with `from=99.999.000, till=100.000.001` - then querying for `X=100.000.000` will touch all partitions, while logically it's good - because only two corresponding rows.

Comment: OK. I understand it better now. Maybe partitioning isn't right here then. Hope you have better luck with another approach.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in any case, Tom

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

I think this is what you need.
But still an full index scan is needed for the 125 case, the 2001 will trigger an better range scan.

```
SELECT 
   data.id
 , data.`from`
 , data.`till`
FROM
 data
WHERE
 `from` < 125 and 125 < `till`
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/208ca/20

**Option 2**

DERIVED table to filter out the non matches

```
SET @x = 125;


SELECT 
   data.id
 , data.`from`
 , data.`till`
FROM (

  SELECT 
      id
   , `till`

  FROM 
   data

  WHERE
   `from` < @x -- from should always be smaller than @x 

) from_filter

INNER JOIN 
 data
ON 
   from_filter.id = data.id
 AND
   @x < from_filter.`till` -- @x should always be smaller then till
;
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/208ca/27

**Option 3**

**R tree indexing may be the best option**

Comment: Thanks - but I don't see how in common case single-column index will solve an issue that is described in question. For example, second option relies on subquery, which in common case will result in full scan (and I want to avoid that). Can you tell more about option 3?

Comment: @Alma Do An B tree compound indexes (multi column indexes) are very powerfull and much better with ranges vs single column indexes because of the better index selectivity (hard to explain)...  Option 2 is an DERIVED what is using an full covering index scan or convering index range scan (fast because you need an range), this is not really an bad subquery.. subqueries are not always bad the correlated subqueries are bad for performance.. Option 3 is really out of mine knowledge never needed this index type...

Comment: I know what B-tree indexes are and what they are doing and how they will work with multiple columns. Well, it seems, I'll need to search information about option 3

Comment: @Alma Do i trust you if you say you know.. and its very true B tree indexes isnt the best approach for this problem (bad for finding values between lower and upper bounds) if you have an SSD disk or RAID 10 config with 15K Disks these queries would scale pretty well but still an R Tree index should perform better. i think i will do the same and learn how to use this index type.